# Array of String to an array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

For Example:

```
var array = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','d','d','d'];

var ans = array.reduce(function(acc,curr){
    if(typeof acc[curr] == 'undefined') {
        acc[curr] = 1;   
    } else {
        acc[curr] += 1;
    }

    return acc;
}, {});
```

will give me:

```
ans = {'a':'2','b':'2','c':'4','d':'6'}
```

But my goal is to get it in this format

```
ans = [{'word':'a','count':'2'},{'word':'b','count':'2'},{'word':'c','count':'4'},{'word':'d','count':'6'}]
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @megawac OP is already using `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: He has syntax errors in his snippets which they can figure out themselves

Comment: my problem is not with reduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a concise data format however, if you must transform it into the more verbose version, try

```
var wordCount = [];
Object.keys(ans).forEach(function(word) {
    wordCount.push({
        word: word,
        count: ans[word]
    });
});
```

If you wanted an all-in-one solution, try this one...

```
var array = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','c','c','d','d','d','d','d','d'];

var ans = array.map(function(word) {
    return { word: word, count: 1 };
}).reduce(function(p, c) {
    for (var i = 0, l = p.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (p[i].word === c.word) {
            p[i].count += c.count;
            return p;
        }
    }
    p.push(c);
    return p;
}, []);
```